# How to get latest date from multiple table in particular row using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

[image]I am trying to develop functionality like facebook, now in home page i want to get all post and status ordering by latest activity e.g like, comment, share. below tried some query mentioned:

```
 (
            SELECT '' as commentstatusid,'' as commentpostid,'' as sharestatusid,'' as sharepostid, '' as likestatusid,'' As lid, s.id AS sid, '' AS shid,'' AS cid  , s.createdDate AS d
            FROM  `tblstatusmanagement` as s LEFT JOIN tblcommentsmanagement as c on s.id = c.statusid WHERE s.status = 'Active' AND s.auther_id IN (1) 
            )
            UNION (
            SELECT  '' as commentstatusid,'' as commentpostid,sh.statusid as sharestatusid,postid as sharepostid,'' as likestatusid,'',  '', sh.id AS shid,'', MAX(createdDate) AS d
            FROM  `tblsharemanagement` as sh LEFT JOIN tblstatusmanagement as s on sh.statusid = s.id 
            LEFT JOIN `tblpostmanagement` as p on p.id = sh.postid 
            WHERE status = 'Active' AND sh.shareuser IN (1) 
            )
    UNION (

            SELECT  '' as commentstatusid,'' as commentpostid,'' as sharestatusid,'' as sharepostid,statusid as likestatusid,id As lid , '', '','', MAX(createdDate) AS d
            FROM  `tbllikesmanagement` as l LEFT JOIN `tblsharemanagement` as sh on sh.id = l.shareid or s.id = l.statusid WHERE status = 'Active' AND user IN (1) 
            )
    UNION (

            SELECT   statusid as commentstatusid,postid as commentpostid,'' as sharestatusid, '' as sharepostid,'' as likestatusid,'','', '', id As cid, MAX(createdDate) AS d
            FROM  `tblcommentsmanagement` as c WHERE s.id =  c.statusid status = 'Active' AND userid IN (1) group by postid,statusid
            )
            ORDER BY d DESC
```

---

```
SELECT s.id AS sid, sh.id AS shid, max( s.createdDate ) AS statusdate, max( sh.createdDate ) AS sharedate, max( l.createdDate ) AS likedate, max( c.createdDate ) AS commentdate
FROM tblstatusmanagement s
LEFT JOIN tblsharemanagement sh ON s.id = sh.statusid
LEFT JOIN tbllikesmanagement l ON l.statusid = s.id
OR l.shareid = sh.id
LEFT JOIN tblcommentsmanagement c ON c.statusid = s.id
GROUP BY s.id, sh.id
ORDER BY max( s.createdDate ) DESC , max( sh.createdDate ) DESC , max( l.createdDate ) DESC , max( c.createdDate ) DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort by a particular date-time column?

Comment: @ nikhil
we are trying to fetch data as per last activity on post or status, different activity e.g like, comments and share.